# Self-signed secure boot initramfs and intel-ucode

Tags: linux, security, encryption, arch-linux

I've set up a self-signed refind and linux kernel. The problem is that intel-ucode and initramfs resides on /boot, which is an unencrypted fat32 `ESP` filesytem - UEFI specific.

How can I secure my initramfs and intel-ucode?

One option is to make the kernel check them against the key or load them from the luks-encrypted root filesystem (ext4), which I don't know if is possible.

The other option is to make the kernel check the signature of them - which as well don't know if is possible.